# Assigning random ID does not work

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am new on JS, I need help on adding a random generated ID to images that when we click appeared on Canvas. These images appeared on Canvas got to be assign an ID. Can anyone give me advice?

On HTML:

```html
<FORM>
   <INPUT type="button" value="+"onClick="Add(new IMGid)"> 
   <input type="text" id="amount" value=0  maxlength="3" size="1" onKeyPress="return numeralsOnly(event)">
   <INPUT type="button" value="-" onClick="Remove()">
</FORM>
```

And on Javascript file:

```js
function Add(new IMGid) {

    newIMG = document.createElement("IMG");
    newIMG.id = "IMG" + newIMGid;
    newIMG = document.getElementById("divIMG1").appendChild(newIMG);

    var uniqueNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999);
    var newIMGid  = newImg.attr('uniqueNum');

    if (document.getElementById('amount').value < 100){
        document.getElementById('amount').value++;
        newIMG = document.createElement("IMG");
        x = Math.random() * 200;
        y = Math.random() * 160;
        c5_context.drawImage(bluefish, x, y, 58, 100).value++;


        //added by Luke 
        a = document.createElement("IMG").setID;
        Element.attr('IMG', 'random');
        //--------------------

        document.getElementById("imagedest").appendChild(newIMG);

        c5_context.drawImage(anchovies, x, y, 58, 100).value++;

        document.write(newIMG);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the rest of your code, specifically the part containing your IMGid object definition?

Comment: This is the only line i have 
"newIMG.id = "IMG" + newIMGid;" 
I am trying to assign and add together the image and ID. How should I do that ?

Comment: The syntax `new Etc` means, 'create a new instance of object `Etc`.  That's a syntax error if you meant otherwise, aside from it being a syntax error in that you are creating a new instance inside a variable declaration.

Comment: how can u advise ??

    newIMG = document.createElement("IMG");
    newIMG.src = 'jef-frog.gif';
    newIMG.width = 1;
    newIMG.height = 1;
    //newIMG.setAttribute('id', "IMG" + newIMGid)

    //newIMG.id = "IMG" + newIMGid;
    //newIMG = document.getElementById("divIMG1").appendChild(newIMG);
    
so I should create a new variable to store the newIMG and the ID ?

Comment: It depends on what you want; your code and your description lead to two different avenues.  As far as I am aware, giving an image, drawn on a canvas, an id is difficult without any libraries.  What you are doing in your code is.. difficult to follow.  You create image elements(which have nothing to do with canvases), and you also refer to variables that apparently don't exist(bluefish, anchovies).

Comment: hi ...cos my canvas is in the html file. Now this is the javascript files which i tried to separate them.

Comment: .. That doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: how can i post more of my code here?

Comment: Edit your question above.  If you had more rep, I would have taken you into chat.

Answer (score 1):

`function Add(new IMGid) {` - syntax error, extra space?

`newIMG.setAttribute('id', "IMG" + newIMGid)` might work a bit better...

```
var newIMGid  = newImg.attr('uniqueNum');
```

1. variable names are case sensitive. Is that `newIMG`?
2. DOM items have no `attr` function... do you use jquery or something?

there are LOTS of errors here... how it is supposed to work at all?

Comment: Actually I am totally new. I just started learning. From online research I found that might need to use JQuery, but have no idea how to do it.

Do i need to set a global variable? How can I assign when ever an image is added and drawn on the canvas?